# How to plan a model analysis that avoids overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, project-planning

Coming from statistics, I'm freshly trying to learn machine learning. I've read a lot of tutorials about ML, but have no real training.

I'm working on a little project where my dataset have 6k lines and around 300 features.

As I've read in my tutorials, I split my dataset into a training sample (80%) and a testing sample (20%), and then train my algorithm on the training sample with cross-validation (5 folds).

As I re-ran my program twice (I've only tested KNN which I now know is quite not appropriate), I got really different results, with different sensitivity, specificity and precision.

I guess that if I re-run the program until metrics are good, my algorithm will be overfitted, and I also guess it would be because of the resample of test/training samples, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

**If I'm going to try a lot of algorithms to see what I can get, should I fix my samples somewhere?** Is it even OK to do try several algorithms? (it would not always be in statistics)

In case it matters, I'm working with python's scikit-learn module.

***PS:** my outcome is binary and my features are mostly binary, with few categorial and few numeric. I'm thinking about logistic, but which algorithm would be the best one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that if I re-run the program until metrics are good, my
>   algorithm will be overfitted

Re-running an algorithm does not contribute to over-fitting. Re-run and select the best model no problem. However, when we try to compare two algorithms we must average over large enough number of re-runs. However, in practice, we want the best *model* not the best *algorithm*.

> I also guess it would be because of the resample of test/training
>   samples, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Re-sampling the training set only contributes to what is known as *model variance*, which denotes the fact that different training samples yield different models.

> As I re-ran my program twice (I've only tested KNN which I now know is
>   quite not appropriate), I got really different results

Your observation is natural. A general approach to decreasing the variance of KNN is to increase the parameter $K$, higher $K$ means KNN looks at more points around a query point (see [these plots](https://kevinzakka.github.io/2016/07/13/k-nearest-neighbor/#more-on-k)).

> If I'm going to try a lot of algorithms to see what I can get, should
>   I fix my samples somewhere?

Random sampling is OK.

In python, [sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html) would build and validate K models for a given algorithm and returns K results; assuming we are feeding 80% of data to K-fold CV, it splits the 80% to 80(K-1)/K% training set and 80/K% validation set for K times.

In summary, first split the data 20%-80%, do cross validation on 80% of data for each algorithm (algorithms would be 1-NN, 2-NN, SVM, etc.), then select a model with the best [validation] accuracy (set `return_estimator = True` to get K models per algorithm from K-fold CV, so for 3 algorithms we are selecting among 3K models), and finally test the best model on the held-out 20% to get the test accuracy; cross-validation has no meaning here since the best model is *already built*. The final result is the test accuracy.

Also, take a look at [this answer on train, validation, test sets](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/47268/67328).

> Is it even OK to do try several algorithms? (it would not always be in statistics)

Yes. Always try various algorithms.

**A side note on parameter finding**

We can apply the above procedure on (1-NN, 2-NN, 3-NN), and if the winner model is always selected from 3-NN algorithm, then we can limit our experiments to only (3-NN, SVM) instead of all the four. Otherwise, if the winner is not consistently from 3-NN, we can experiment with all the four.

Comment: Maybe terms were lost in translation but I learned that you should use 3 samples (training, validation and test) and that you can use cross validation (with `model_selection.cross_validate`) on the two formers to auto-selected the best K hyperparameter (hence having only 2 populations is ok). I'm a bit confused here, should I do cross validation on the test sample too ? With `model_selection.cross_validate` too ?

Comment: Thanks for your edits. So crossvalidation is not only used to select hyperparameters (the KNN's K) but also to select models type (KNN vs logistic) ?

Comment: A last real-world question if I may. If I'm working several days on some project, the code which split my population into train and test (`model_selection.train_test_split` in `scikit`) will be called each day. Is this an issue ? If yes, is there a optimized method to deal with it or should I just save the result as `train.csv` and `test.csv`?

Comment: @DanChaltiel For the sake of comparability of test results among models built over many days, you may do the splitting only once to have a fixed final test set. This way you can say model 1 from day 1 with test accuracy 90% is better than model N from day D with test accuracy 88%, since the test set is the same.